# How to get the mssql output in protractor + VSCode

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typescript, visual-studio-code, protractor

I'm running the below code seems like the connection is made successfully but i do not see any output or is there any way to see the output of the query result, I'm new to this protractor nodeJS MSSQL connection.

```
const assert = require("../configuration.js");
const { config } = require("dotenv");
const { ConnectionPool } = require("mssql");
var sql = require('mssql');

config();

const c = {
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  server: "server/nameORIP",
  user: "UserName",
  password: "Password",
  database: 'DBname',
};

describe("mssql connection", () => {

  it('test query', () => {

    sql.connect(config, (err) => {

      if (err) console.log(err);

      // create Request object
      var request = new sql.Request();

      // query to the database and get the records
      request.query('select * from NetUsers', (err, recordset) => {

        if (err) console.log(err)
        // send records as a response
        request.send(recordset);
      });

    }); // end of sql.connect()

  }) // end of it
})
```

Output

```
Request {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  canceled: false,
  _paused: false,
  parent: [Function: ConnectionPool],
  parameters: {},
  rowsAffected: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it to work with few changes not only it connects but also runs the query and shows me the output in console, once again thank you for all the help.

```
import { async } from "q";
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const assert = require("../configuration.js");

const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    server: "server/nameORIP",
    user: "UserName",
    password: "Password",
    database: 'DBname',
})
.connect()
  .then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err))
;

describe('any test', () => {

    it('verification', async () => {

        try
        {
            const pool = await poolPromise;

            const result = await pool.request()
            .query('SELECT TOP (10) * FROM dbo.NetUsers')

            console.log(result);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any information for the method `request.send(recordset);` from their official documentation.

Supported methods in Request Object are:

1. execute - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#execute
2. input  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#input
3. output  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#output
4. pipe  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#pipe
5. query  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#query
6. batch  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#batch
7. bulk  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulk
8. cancel - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#cancel

`request.query` function will give you the list of records from the DB and pass it to the callback function and the values can be accessed directly using

```
request.query('select * from NetUsers', (err, resultArray) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    // if no error
    console.log(resultArray.recordset[0]); //will print the first row from response.
  });
```

Refer : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#query-command-callback